# The uniqueness of wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We know that for 1-d wave equation, the solution $u$ can be represented by d'Alembert's formula, does that mean that the solution of heat equation is unique on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$? The uniqueness can be proven if $f,g$ have compact support, what if not?

Comment: You meant wave equation instead of heat.

Comment: If you say that "*the* solution can be represented by..." you are assuming that there is only one... it really depends on *how* you got to D'Alembert's formula.whether you know it gives the only solution or not. Your question, as stated, has no answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am thinking if all the solution of wave equation can be represented by d'Alambert formula